# The status link on the maintenance page is hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The final remaining artefact of our blue background?

[image]

Comment: Yes, the green "Illegible" text is kinda hard to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fixed and will be out in the next build.